# How increase loop with Xquery?

Tags: for-loop, xquery, exist-db

how i can increase loop **fourteenth by fourteenth with xquery** . For example i have this loop :

```
for $i in (0 to 150)
return $i
```

I want increase this loop fourteenth by fourteenth .Output:

```
14

28

42

56

70

etc.
```

I am working on exist-db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for $i in (0 to 150)
return ($i+1)*14
```

Comment: Or:for $i in (1 to 151)
return $i*14

Answer (score 2):

Most simple – and probably easiest to read – approach would be to **filter the sequence using the modulo function**, but this has the disadvantage that all 150 values have to be constructed:

```
(1 to 150)[. mod 14 = 0]
```

Using the approach @prker used, you have to calculate the upper bound on your own. `idiv` is the integer division operator.

```
for $i in (1 to 150 idiv 14)
return $i * 14
```

Using XQuery 3.0, you could also use the **apply operator** `!` instead:

```
(1 to 150 idiv 14) ! (. * 14)
```

Or finally by using a **recursive function**:

```
declare function local:n-sequence($from as xs:integer, $to as xs:integer, $step as xs:integer) {
  if ($from > $to)
  then ()
  else ($from, local:n-sequence($from + $step, $to, $step))
};

local:n-sequence(1, 150, 14)
```